# Thread is denied access to file (Update Impersonation)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC .NET application I have an action on a controller that takes some documents and does some processing.  The processing can take a long time to finish so I decided to start a thread to do the work while the users can go off and do more work.  However, when I start a new thread through

```
Thread thread = new Thread(finishedDocument.SplitAndIndex);
thread.Start();
```

the thread gets an UnauthorizedAccessException.  The method is accessing some files on a server but if I do just `finishedDocument.SplitAndIndex`
(so not inside a thread) it runs just fine.  I've ensured that all resources are released but even to test if that was the case I put a file out there called test.txt and the only part of my application that touches it is in that method, and still I get the error.

I thought that threads were supposed to have the same permissions/privileges as the process/thread that created it.  Is that not the case?  Is there something I should be doing?  I'm really at a loss here and any help would be great.

**Update**
I know it has to do with impersonation, I just can't seem to get a thread safe way to do impersonation now.

Comment: Try doing the same using the Task stuff

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it does the same thing.

Comment: doing "start a thread to do the work while the users can go off and do more work" is very risky thing in asp.net. You *really* should not do work that survives the page lifecycle from inside the website. Either use a framework that reduces the risk, like [hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/) or write a external program or service that can run on the server that runs outside of IIS to do the long running work.

Comment: @Tyler the task stuff should work provided you've passed in the right options (intelisense and MSDN are your friends ;) )

Comment: I would agree with @ScottChamberlain regarding hangfire; I've used it heavily for long running tasks, although if you only have the one thing, then it's a bit of overkill...